# Selenium, turning a headless chrome driver into a regular one a user can interact with?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, driver

My goal is to run about two dozen headless chrome drivers on a page that periodically refreshes on its own. I want the headless driver to become able to be interacted by the user once the driver detects a certain key word that appears in the page source that events randomly for each session.

Is turning a headless chrome driver into a regular one a user can see and interact with feasible? Another idea I had that might work is “transferring” the headless chrome driver’s session and cookies into a regular chrome driver, but again, I am not sure how feasible this is.

I want to use headless drivers for the first part because they don’t clutter the screen and they are fast.

Comment: That sounds like an odd use case and maybe not what you actually want. What are you actually trying to achieve by running these headless Chrome instances? It's likely there's a better way to do it.

Comment: Each instance is to monitor a page and once it detects a change (which occurs randomly for each instance), the user should be able to interact with it. ;;; Think of it like a lottery, the more instances the user has, the higher their chances of getting that random change in the page. I’ve coded this using purely chrome drivers, but it’s somewhat slow and my computer can only handle like 30 instances before it starts to crash.

Comment: So it's waiting for some kind of Javascript event?

Comment: I’m not sure if it’s Javascript, but basically, the page the browsers are monitoring is a queue page. The page refreshes on its own, and eventually the browser is let through the queue once they get a HMAC cookie. When and if getting the HMAC cookie is random for each instance, so I want to maximize the chances by increasing the number of instances. The idea worked with regular chrome drivers but I want something that will be cleaner and less strain on my computer.

Comment: Does it have to refresh or can it just send another request? If you can just make repeated requests then you can use something very basic like Curl or Guzzle to fetch the page. Otherwise you'll be stuck using something that can execute Javascript, which in practice would limit you to things like headless Chrome or PhantomJS.

Comment: To clarify, I don’t refresh the page; the page refreshes itself every ~20 seconds. It tells you “please don’t refresh or you’ll lose your place in queue”.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I came up with a cool work around. Hopes this help anyone who has the same problem! :)

```
user_agent = # user agent 
chrome_path= # path to chrome driver

# headless driver
chrome_options=Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("headless")
chrome_options.add_argument('user-agent={'+user_agent+'}')
driver1=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path, chrome_options=chrome_options)

# let headless driver do its thing..., like log in.. etc

# switch to interactive browser when ready
profile_path=str(driver1.capabilities["chrome"]["userDataDir"])
chrome_options=Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir="+profile_path)
chrome_options.add_argument('user-agent={'+user_agent+'}')
chrome_options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path, chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url)
for cookie in [i for i in driver1.get_cookies() if i not in driver.get_cookies()]:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
driver.refresh() # should be what you expect :)
```